# header not found in first C++ program in Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

I followed this link to set up Netbeans in Windows 8 for first time C++ programming.
[Setting up SDL and Netbeans on Windows 7](http://blog.housmous.com/2012/01/setting-up-sdl-and-netbeans-on-windows-7/).
I've set up the 3 ...a files correctly in the project library and I've also copied the SDL.dll file to the dist\Debug\MinGW-Windows folder. But when I build the project, it failed with "No such file or directory" at the
`#include <SDL\SDL.h>`
Please help.

Comment: Is that an existing project or are you starting a new one?

Comment: it's a new one created by following the steps in the link

Comment: Then you should be better off using the new SDL2 instead of SDL1. SDL1 should generally be used only for old existing projects.

Comment: But aside from that, have you tried simply `#include <SDL.h>`?

Comment: Tried without the SDL/, still the same problem. I am targeting Raspberry Pi to run the final program and I've already installed v1.2 on it.

Comment: So is Netbeans is set up to use that MinGW installation? And did you remember to copy the header files to the include directory? If so, did you copy the include directory into the include directory, or the SDL directory(inside the include directory) into the include directory?

Comment: Using backslash in `#include <…>` has undefined behavior. Try forward slash.